# how create one common onClickListener for multiple check boxes

Tags: android, checkbox

Hi I am new to android programming world and I am stuck with this issue where I want to have one common onClickListener or onCheckChangedListener for all multiple checkBox in the view.

In most of the forums I have gone through they suggest to implement OnClickListener to each of the checkBox and I felt that is not a good idea and feel its a unnecessary overhead.
So the requirement is I have days related checkBoxes, each day representing Sunday to Saturday along with EveryDay. I need to deselect all days checked when Everyday is checked and deselect EveryDay checkBox when any other day is Checked.

Below code I tried but control never reaches inside onClickListener.

```
public class AddEditGroupActivity extends Activity 
        implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.addedit_restrict_byeveryday) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bysunday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bymonday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bytuesday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bywednesday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bythursday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_byfriday)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_bysaturday)).setChecked(false);
            }
        } else if(v.getId() != R.id.addedit_restrict_byeveryday) {
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
                ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.addedit_restrict_byeveryday)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest what is the way forward to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use radioButton instead.

Comment: is it possible to select multiple days with radio button?

Comment: and who has voted this question down is anything wrong with the question?? do you have any idea

Comment: No, it is not posible to select multiple ones if they are of the same group.

I did not downvote the question.

Comment: thanks, I know u did not downvote the question but I am casually asking do you find anything wrong with my question and someone down voted me?? ya with radio button we can't but my requirement is I should be able to select multiple days.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sports:
                            if (checked)
                                uChoice.add("sport");
                            else
                                findAndRemove("sport");

                            break;

    }
}
```

And your layout file

```
  <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sports"
            android:id="@+id/sport"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            />
 <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Business"
            android:id="@+id/bus"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sport"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sport"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```